# Google Api Oath Exception Issues

Tags: php

I am newer to the Google Plus Api, but I have followed each and every rule to integrate G-Plus API in my WEB. But every time I get stuck at the issue:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'apiAuthException' with message 'Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: ''' in C:\AppServ\www\googleplus-source\google-api-php-client\src\auth\apiOAuth2.php:203
Stack trace:
#0 C:\AppServ\www\googleplus-source\google-api-php-client\src\io\apiCurlIO.php(51): apiOAuth2->sign(Object(apiHttpRequest))
#1 C:\AppServ\www\googleplus-source\google-api-php-client\src\io\apiREST.php(55): apiCurlIO->authenticatedRequest(Object(apiHttpRequest))
#2 C:\AppServ\www\googleplus-source\google-api-php-client\src\service\apiServiceResource.php(148): apiREST::execute(Object(apiServiceRequest)) 
#3 C:\AppServ\www\googleplus-source\google-api-php-client\src\contrib\apiPlusService.php(204): apiServiceResource->__call('get', Array)
#4 C:\AppServ\www\googleplus-source\google-plus-access.php(40): PeopleServiceResource->get('me')
#5 C:\AppServ\www\googleplus-source\index.php(2): include_once('C:\AppServ\www\...')
#6 {main} thrown in C:\AppServ\www\googleplus-source\google-api-php-client\src\auth\apiOAuth2.php on line 203
```

What could be the reason for this error?

Comment: Errors are hard to debug without code.

Comment: You should post the code that causes this error, because the problem will most likely be there.

Answer (score 0):

> What could be the reason for this error?

The reason for this error (a *Fatal error*) is given in the error message: *Uncaught exception*. That means [an exception<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/exception) has been thrown and was not caught. This results in a fatal error.

Most likely in your case, the root cause of the problem highlighted in the exception message is misconfiguration and/or wrong API usage. As you have not posted any code in your question, you should read the API documentation first and double check your usage of the API and it's configuration.